# increasing record time in android?

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, frequency

I have  a frequency indicator sound recorder which record sound successfully but it record for only 4 seconds.I need more than 4 seconds to record the code is given below:

```
public class vr1 extends Activity 
{

private static final int SAMPLE_RATE_IN_HZ = 8000;
private static final int RECORDER_BPP      = 16;
private static final int CHANNEL_CONFIG    = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private static final int AUDIO_FORMAT      = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
private static final int AUDIO_SOURCE      = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;
private static final String TAG            = "VoiceDetection";
private static final int MAX_VOL           = 600;
//private static final int MAX_VOL           = 15000;
private static final int MIN_VAL           = 0;
private static final int START_RECORD_FROM = 350;
private static final int CHECK_BLOCK_COUNT = 3;


private Thread onCreateThread     = null;
private AudioRecord audioRecorder = null;
private int minBufferSizeInBytes  = 0;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.porec);

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3); 
    Button button     = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setVisibility( android.view.View.INVISIBLE );
    textView.setVisibility( android.view.View.VISIBLE );

    Start();
}

public void Start( )
{
    // Create Handler
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {

         @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
         {
             int value         = msg.what;
             ImageView picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

             int resID[] = { 
                             R.drawable.image0001, R.drawable.image20, R.drawable.image40,
                             R.drawable.image60,   R.drawable.image80, R.drawable.image100
                           };

             for( int i=MIN_VAL, step = (MAX_VOL - MIN_VAL)/resID.length; i<resID.length; i++ ) {
                 if( value >= i*step && value <= i*step + step )
                     picture.setImageResource( resID[i] );
             }

             // Set image for maximum value.
             if( value >= MAX_VOL )
                 picture.setImageResource( R.drawable.image100 );
         }
    };

    // Text change handler
    final Handler changeTexthandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3); 
            Button button     = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

            switch( msg.what )
            {
                case 0: 
                    textView.setText("Waiting");
                    button.setVisibility( android.view.View.INVISIBLE );
                    textView.setVisibility( android.view.View.VISIBLE );
                    break;
                case 1:
                    textView.setText("Recording");
                    button.setVisibility( android.view.View.INVISIBLE );
                    textView.setVisibility( android.view.View.VISIBLE );
                    break;
                default:
                    button.setVisibility( android.view.View.VISIBLE );
                    textView.setVisibility( android.view.View.INVISIBLE );
                    break;

            }

        }

    };

    // Initialize minimum buffer size in bytes.
    minBufferSizeInBytes = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize( SAMPLE_RATE_IN_HZ,
                                                         CHANNEL_CONFIG,
                                                         AUDIO_FORMAT
                                                        );

    if( minBufferSizeInBytes == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE )
        Log.e( TAG, "Bad Value for \"minBufferSize\", recording parameters are not supported by the hardware" );

    if( minBufferSizeInBytes == AudioRecord.ERROR )
        Log.e( TAG, "Bad Value for \"minBufferSize\", implementation was unable to query the hardware for its output properties" );

    // Initialize Audio Recorder.
    try {
        audioRecorder = new AudioRecord( AUDIO_SOURCE,
                                         SAMPLE_RATE_IN_HZ,
                                         CHANNEL_CONFIG,
                                         AUDIO_FORMAT,
                                         minBufferSizeInBytes 
                                        );
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.e( TAG, "Illegal Arguments: " + ex.getMessage() );
    }

    // Launch Thread.
    onCreateThread = new Thread( new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            // Starts recording from the AudioRecord instance. 
            audioRecorder.startRecording();

            int numberOfBytesRead  = 0;
            byte audioBuffer[]     = new byte[minBufferSizeInBytes];
            float tempBuffer[]     = new float[CHECK_BLOCK_COUNT];
            int tempIndex          = 0;
            boolean isRecording    = false;
            int totalReadBytes     = 0;
            byte totalByteBuffer[] = new byte[60 * 44100 * 2];

            // While data coming from microphone.
            while( true )
            {
                float totalAbsValue = 0.0f;
                short sample        = 0; 
                numberOfBytesRead   = audioRecorder.read( audioBuffer, 0, minBufferSizeInBytes );

                // Analyze income sound. 
                for( int i=0; i<minBufferSizeInBytes; i+=2 ) {
                    sample = (short)( (audioBuffer[i]) | audioBuffer[i + 1] << 8 );
                    totalAbsValue += Math.abs( sample ) / (numberOfBytesRead/2);
                }

                // Set Animation of microphone.
                handler.sendEmptyMessage((int)totalAbsValue);

                // Analyze tempBuffer.
                tempBuffer[tempIndex%CHECK_BLOCK_COUNT] = totalAbsValue;
                float tempBufferTotalCount              = 0.0f;
                for( int i=0; i<CHECK_BLOCK_COUNT; ++i )
                    tempBufferTotalCount += tempBuffer[i];

                // Finalize value.
                tempBufferTotalCount = tempBufferTotalCount/CHECK_BLOCK_COUNT;

                // Waiting for load speak to start recording.
                if( (tempBufferTotalCount >=0 && tempBufferTotalCount <= START_RECORD_FROM) && !isRecording )
                {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Waiting for voice to start record.");
                    tempIndex++;
                    changeTexthandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    continue;
                }

                if( tempBufferTotalCount > START_RECORD_FROM && !isRecording )
                {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Recording");
                    changeTexthandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                    isRecording = true;
                }

                // Stop Recording and save data to file.
                if( (tempBufferTotalCount >= 0 && tempBufferTotalCount <= START_RECORD_FROM) && isRecording )
                {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Stop Recording and Save data to file");
                    changeTexthandler.sendEmptyMessage(2);  

                    audioRecorder.stop();
                    audioRecorder.release();
                    audioRecorder = null;


                    SaveDataToFile( totalReadBytes, totalByteBuffer );
                    totalReadBytes = 0; 

                    tempIndex++;
                    break;
                }

                // Record Sound.
                for( int i=0; i<numberOfBytesRead; i++ )    
                    totalByteBuffer[totalReadBytes + i] = audioBuffer[i];

                totalReadBytes += numberOfBytesRead;
                tempIndex++;
            }

        }

    }, "Voice Detection Thread" );

    // Run the Thread.
    onCreateThread.start();
    //*/
}

public void SaveDataToFile( int totalReadBytes, byte[] totalByteBuffer )
{
    // Save audio to file.
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File( filepath, "VioceDetectionDemo" );
    if( !file.exists( ) )
        file.mkdirs();

    // String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".wav";
    // File always saved by same name.
    String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "VoiceDetectionDemo" + ".wav";

    long totalAudioLen  = 0;
    long totalDataLen   = totalAudioLen + 36;
    long longSampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE_IN_HZ;
    int channels        = 1;
    long byteRate       = RECORDER_BPP * SAMPLE_RATE_IN_HZ * channels/8;
    totalAudioLen       = totalReadBytes;
    totalDataLen        = totalAudioLen + 36;
    byte finalBuffer[]  = new byte[totalReadBytes + 44];

    finalBuffer[0]  = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
    finalBuffer[1]  = 'I';
    finalBuffer[2]  = 'F';
    finalBuffer[3]  = 'F';
    finalBuffer[4]  = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
    finalBuffer[5]  = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    finalBuffer[6]  = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    finalBuffer[7]  = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
    finalBuffer[8]  = 'W';
    finalBuffer[9]  = 'A';
    finalBuffer[10] = 'V';
    finalBuffer[11] = 'E';
    finalBuffer[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
    finalBuffer[13] = 'm';
    finalBuffer[14] = 't';
    finalBuffer[15] = ' ';
    finalBuffer[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
    finalBuffer[17] = 0;
    finalBuffer[18] = 0;
    finalBuffer[19] = 0;
    finalBuffer[20] = 1;  // format = 1
    finalBuffer[21] = 0;
    finalBuffer[22] = (byte) channels;
    finalBuffer[23] = 0;
    finalBuffer[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
    finalBuffer[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    finalBuffer[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    finalBuffer[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    finalBuffer[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
    finalBuffer[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    finalBuffer[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    finalBuffer[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    finalBuffer[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8);  // block align
    finalBuffer[33] = 0;
    finalBuffer[34] = RECORDER_BPP;  // bits per sample
    finalBuffer[35] = 0;
    finalBuffer[36] = 'd';
    finalBuffer[37] = 'a';
    finalBuffer[38] = 't';
    finalBuffer[39] = 'a';
    finalBuffer[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
    finalBuffer[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    finalBuffer[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    finalBuffer[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

    for( int i=0; i<totalReadBytes; ++i )
        finalBuffer[44+i] = totalByteBuffer[i];

    FileOutputStream out;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
         try {
                out.write(finalBuffer);
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void OnClickButtonTryAgain(View view)
{
    Start();
}
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: what that about? i need to record more that 4 sec please give me a solution guys?

Comment: See [this link](http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/). You'll get a much more precise answer if you ask a more precise question. (Are you trying to record to a file? To SD card? To memory? In what format? It's hard to tell from the code, since we know the code doesn't actually do what you want. Do you want a more compressed format so more will fit in memory? Do you not know how to record to a file? Or do you not want to record to a file?)

Comment: i want to record voice which is stored in memorycard(sd card) in.wav format.the above code is working i just need to know how to increase the recording length.the link you have send that it have already checked but it does not produce a indicator when sound is being recorder